# Revolution! with Anarchy expansion: when does the game end?

Tags: revolution, revolution-anarchy

Normally, Revolution! ends when all influence squares are filled. The Anarchy expansion adds Garden, Asylum, and Jail --- do these also need to get filled for the game to end? If so, how do you avoid a mad frenzy over jail and asylum in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a copy of the rules, but the expansion seems to consist of a [board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb0xA.jpg) that replaces certain districts like [The Palace](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/67731/revolution-palace) did. I don't see why the end-of-game would be any different than without the expansion.

As for end-of-game frenzy, there's always a lot of cube manipulations at the end of the game. The person in the lead tries to end the game, while the others are vying to move cubes instead of adding them (or they are trying to get the resources to win the roles that would allow them to do so). Nothing new here.